# Converting LDR to HDR in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, hdrimages

I cant seem to find a data structure in opencv which can hold pixel depths greater than 8 bits. My problem is that i would like to take a LDR image and multiply some of the pixels so that these pixel's value would exceed the 255 boundary. This is what i have tried so far. I have tried mapping the pixel values from 0-1,  instead of 0-255, then multiplying them with a scalar(to increase their value). But when i need to write the image again, the image is dark unless i multiply with 255. i hope you can help me :)

```
Mat ApplySunValue(Mat InputImg){


Mat OutPutImg = Mat::zeros(InputImg.rows, InputImg.cols, CV_32FC1);


for(int x = 0; x < OutPutImg.cols; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < OutPutImg.rows; y++){

        int PixelValue = InputImg.at<uchar>(y,x)/255.f;

        if(PixelValue < 0.9){
            OutPutImg.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0;
        }else{
            OutPutImg.at<uchar>(y,x) = PixelValue * sunMultiplyer;
        }
    }
}

imwrite("/Users/K******/Desktop/EnviormentMap.jpg", OutPutImg * 255);

namedWindow("Hej", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Hej", OutPutImg * 255);



return OutPutImg;
```

}

Comment: your problem might be that you try to access `OutputImg` as `uchar` but your image is `CV_32FC1` type. Try `OutPutImg.at<float>(y,x) = PixelValue * sunMultiplyer;`. Be careful that float image displaying uses values between 0 and 1 only because it's internally multiplied by 255, so `imshow("Hej", OutPutImg * 255);` might be changed to not scale the image there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be always 0 (integer division):

```
int PixelValue = InputImg.at<uchar>(y,x)/255.f;
```

PixelValue is integer, so your comparison is BS:

```
if(PixelValue < 0.9){
```

as @Micka already spotted, you have to use the correct type for at():

```
OutPutImg.at<float>(y,x) = 299.0f; 
// yes, can be larger than 255 now, so you can discard your broken mapping attempts
```

you can't save or read floating point images as jpeg or png. check if your opencv libs were built with exr support:

```
cerr << cv::getBuildInformation() << endl;
```

if so, you can save/read it as *.hdr or *.exr